# Uber API invalid grant error?

Tags: php, curl, uber-api

I've been struggling to understand and find my way through the Uber API and their useless documentation.

I managed to put together this code in PHP which uses `CURL` to get an `authorization_code` code so I can further use that in other parts of my PHP page. For example, `request a ride` etc...

However, when I run my code, I get this error:

```
{"error": "invalid_grant"}
```

I searched high and low on Google and STO to see if i could find a solid answer to this but unfortunately nothing seems to give an straight forward answer and I'm stuck at this stage.

This is my code:

```
<?php
    $fields_string = '';
    $fields = array(
        'client_secret' => '57KC5WGG3Ia455lc-i53e345345znXBB_0',
        'client_id' => 'nnV4-_lsG9xl-SbAIQjIhwer234534534',
        'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
        'redirect_uri' => "http://localhost:3000/auth/uber/callback",
        'code' => $_GET['code']
    );
    foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
    rtrim($fields_string, '&');
    $ch = curl_init();   
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, "https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/token");
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $responseData = json_decode($result , TRUE);
    $access_token = $responseData["access_token"];
    echo "Access Token :" . $access_token ;
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

it might be worth mentioning that, the above code is all that I have in my php page. nothing else.

**Questions:**

1. Is there something that i am missing?
2. Do I need to do anything in my Uber developer dashboard?
3. Do I need to do anything else in my php page?

Any help or pointers that is laymen terms and make sense would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions taken from: https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v2/token-post

1. You are using an invalid refresh_token. You can generate multiple access tokens, but you can only use the latest generated refresh_token.
2. You supplied an invalid code when exchanging an authorization code for an access_token.

Comment: I did find that myself. however, what doesn't make sense is the fact that nowhere explains what 'refresh_token' is and where and how to generate it.

Comment: I am not familiar with Uber's API, but it seems to be explained here.
[Refresh Token](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v2/token-post#example-request-refresh-token)